# In postgresql how can I select rows where a jsonb array contains objects?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

My database table is something like this (data is a JSONB column):

```
 id |                 data                 
----+--------------------------------------
  1 | {"tags": [{"name": "tag1"}, {"name": "tag2"}]}
  2 | {"tags": [{"name": "tag2"}]}
  3 | {"tags": [{"name": "tag3"}]}
  4 | {"tags": [{"name": "tag4"}]}
```

I'd like to write a query that will return the rows where `data` contains tags `tag2` or `tag3`. So rows 1, 2, and 3 should be returned.
I've been looking at the postgresql JSONB documentation and it's not clear to me how to query a nested structure like this. How would I write the where clause?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using where exists with a filter on the unnested json array will return the rows with id 1, 2 & 3

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT TRUE 
    FROM jsonb_array_elements(data->'tags') x 
    WHERE x->>'name' IN ('tag2', 'tag3')
)
```

Answer (score 17):

`jsonb_array_elements` would harm the performance. If that is a concern, you can use this query instead

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable where 
    data @> '[{"name": "tag2"}]'::jsonb 
    or 
    data @> '[{"name": "tag3"}]'::jsonb;
```

Comment: How does this work without having to specify the top level field `tags`? What if there was another top level field that was also an array, would it search within that as well?

Answer (score 0):

let's say:

```
db=# create table so33(id int, data jsonb);
CREATE TABLE
db=# copy so33 from stdin delimiter '|';
Enter data to be copied followed by a newline.
End with a backslash and a period on a line by itself.
>>   1 | {"tags": [{"name": "tag1"}, {"name": "tag2"}]}
  2 | {"tags": [{"name": "tag2"}]}
  3 | {"tags": [{"name": "tag3"}]}
  4 | {"tags": [{"name": "tag4"}]}>> >> >>
>> \.
COPY 4
```

[then](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html):

```
db=# with c as (select *,jsonb_array_elements(data->'tags')->>'name' e from so33)
select * from c where e in ('tag2','tag3');
 id |                      data                      |  e
----+------------------------------------------------+------
  1 | {"tags": [{"name": "tag1"}, {"name": "tag2"}]} | tag2
  2 | {"tags": [{"name": "tag2"}]}                   | tag2
  3 | {"tags": [{"name": "tag3"}]}                   | tag3
(3 rows)
```

A simple `jsonb_array_elements` should do

obviously `SELECT DISTINCT id, data FROM e` should give your expected result